# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" when compiling lex and yacc

Tags: gcc, bison, yacc, lex

Lex and Yacc work, but when I try to compile the y.tab.c file, I'm getting the following error. I have a feeling its a linking issue where compiler can't find the library that it needs, but I have no idea how to fix it.

In my nor.y file, I have this at the top:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
```

In my nor.l file, I have this at the top:

```
 %{
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
extern YYSTYPE yylval;
%}
```

Then, when I try to compile with

```
gcc y.tab.h -ly -ll
```

I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_yyparse", referenced from:
  _main in liby.a(main.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It should probably be `gcc y.tab.c -ly -ll` not `gcc y.tab.h -ly -ll`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the .c files, not the header file:

```
gcc y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll
```